# Importing .so file in Windows generated in Linux

Tags: python, cython

I working on one stuff which is taking a lot of time to execute by using Python code in Windows OS. Hence I decided to use Cython. But in Windows 10 configuring c compiler by using Mingw, felt like a lot of things to done and its not working also. Hence decided to go with Linux to generate .so file and later use that in windows by importing it.

First of all my question, Is that possible to import in windows a .so generated in Linux. If Yes, How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While it's technically possible, it's almost certainly not what you want or reasonable effort. Some methods that come to mind are using a loader (also known as dynamic linker) that understands the appropriate format, such as the venerable cross-elf ([archive.org snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/19990117033603/http://www.planet.net/pjoshv/cross-elf.html)), use an emulation layer such as [qemu](https://www.qemu.org/), or a high level virtualization shim like [User-mode Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-mode_Linux). In each of these cases, you'd need to run your entire CPython under that same layer, which means it wouldn't have access to Windows features. One of the few projects that did go as far as implementing their own dynamic linker is [XFree86](http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/RELNOTES4.html).